# IIS server unable to access the file path

Tags: windows, iis

I have installed web application behind IIS which access the files/directory located on the another machine.

Now while developing the application using the Visual Studio 2008 then Developer Web Server it provides when build the site was able to access the location. However when the site is deployed on the IIS its saying Unable to access the file because of insufficient permissions.

Can some one please help regarding what could be the issue ? any idea or pointers could be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for naming, your web application is located in WebServer1 and need to access files on FileServer2, right?

So, here's my checklist...
WebServer1 and FileServer2 are both on the same network? 
ping between results? Windows Firewall enable?
WebServer1 have a mapped drive to FileServer2 files directory?
Do you have assign IUSR_ (Internet Guest Account) read permissions to the FileServer2 mapped directory?
Regards,